# curl writes to cookie jar file, but does not appear to read

Tags: curl

I am not using PHP CURL, but simply running as a command line as follows:

```
curl -i -L -c cookies/mywebsite.com.txt -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0' https://www.mywebsite.com/
```

printing the results, I am receiving a `Set-Cookie` in the header for PHPSESSID, so on initial contact the site is setting a session cookie, and I verify that the cookie jar file `cookies/mywebsite.com.txt` is set with this information.

However, I suspect that curl, on the next page call I make (for example to `https://www.mywebsite.com/about-us`), is not sending the previous page's cookie info, as I note that I'm again getting a `Set-Cookie` header line, but with a different PHPSESSID value.

Is there any way of verifying this, and what might be causing it?

NOTE: permissions are not a problem as the cookie jar file is owned by www-data (apache user) and also obviously it's getting written to.  It's just not persisting the session, and I don't know how to know what curl is sending OUT as a header, only what it's receiving.

Answer (score 6):

In order to both send and receive cookies, I found I needed to do the following with BOTH the `-b` and `-c` switches:

```
curl -i -L -b cookies/mywebsite.com -c cookies/mywebsite.com.txt -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0' https://www.mywebsite.com/
```

I found and used the LAST example in section 9.2 here:
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Cookie_Basics

except that I use obviously the same file name for both.

This solved the problem.  Hope this helps someone else.